# How could I get the information from a json in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get the information from the json without using future builder or list builder to be able to use it in a usser acount header.
I want to get the information from the json without using future builder or list builder to be able to use it in a usser acount header.

help would be greatly appreciated

help would be greatly appreciated

code::

```
-- S

ervices--
             Future <List>InfoCabeceraDrawer() async{
                Map<String, String> headers = {
                  'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                  'Charset':'utf-8'
                };
            
                var Url= Uri.parse("http://");
                final response = await http.get((Url),headers: headers);
                print(response.body);
                return productDrawerFromJson(response.body);
              }
            
            --- Model--
            List productCabeceraDrawerFromJson(String str) => List<CabeceraDrawerModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => CabeceraDrawerModel.fromJson(x)));// con esto hago el get
            
            class CabeceraDrawerModel{
            
              String UsuarioPk;
              String FotoUsuario;
              String CorreoUsuario;
              String NombreUsuario;
            
              CabeceraDrawerModel({this.UsuarioPk,this.FotoUsuario,this.NombreUsuario,this.CorreoUsuario});
            
              factory CabeceraDrawerModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
                return CabeceraDrawerModel(
                    UsuarioPk: parsedJson['Usu'],
                    FotoUsuario:parsedJson['im'],
                    NombreUsuario: parsedJson['Usuar'],
                    CorreoUsuario:parsedJson['Usuario_C']
                );
              }
            
            }
            
            -- front--
            
         @override
          void initState() {
            
        
            super.initState();
          }
        
              UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
     accountName: Text("show information data base"),
        accountEmail:Text(""),
  ),
```

Comment: can you calrify more on what you're expecting to be done ?

Comment: What I want is to get each value of the json to be able to show it in usser acount header in the accountName and accountEmail properties.
example::
Acountname::Text(UserName);

or
AcountEmail:Text(data["EmailUser"]) but without using list.builder or a future builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the value from JSON into the state, and display the state values in the ui

Comment: To do this, you will have to use stateful widget

Comment: Could you help me with an example?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).